# Microsoft SSO does not work sometimes in asp.net owin

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-sign-on, owin

I am facing a weird bug in my asp.net application where even after successful authentication from Microsoft side I was not able to sign in my application.However this happens intermittently
I have seen multiple reports of the issue on the internet but not sure it is related to my issue